# Can CPPredicates be used on native javascript objects?

Tags: javascript, cappuccino, objective-j

Can you use a CPPredicate to check native javascript objects in cappuccino? I am trying to filter a native javascript array that has native javascript objects in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not likely to work. Objective-J objects have a few more features than JS object which I'm sure the predicate advantage of.

You can easily convert JS objects to CPDictionaries and back again though.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using a cappuccino object that holds a raw JS object and implements getKeyForPath which is now working. The way you suggested is the correct answer as well.